# What is the Use of Lucene?

Tags: java, lucene, web-crawler

i have heard lot of time the name Lucene , while i try to fetch details of web crawler it show up most of time.whats the use of Lucene?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lucene is a search engine library designed to address the problem of performing keyword search over a large number of documents.  The system works by processing the documents to extract all of the words, and then creating a reverse index.  This index allows the search engine to quickly identify the documents containing the user's search term or terms, rank them, and then return them to the user.

Lucene supports a variety of advanced features such as phrase queries, wildcard queries and proximity queries (i.e. "cat" near "dog"), search for keywords within particular "fields" (e.g. subject, author) and so on.

Basically, it is one of the ways to add text search capability to document management applications of various kinds.

Comment: This is a nice description. However, Lucene is not a search engine. It is a search library. You always have to embed Lucene inside a program (in Java, or one of the languages Lucene was ported to) in order to use it. Solr is a search engine based on Lucene.

Comment: The Lucene site describes Lucene as a "search engine library" ... so I think you may be splitting hairs.

Comment: I don't think this is splitting hairs. IMO, Saying Lucene is a search engine implies that you can use it out-of-the-box for searching. I do not think this is possible.

Comment: It doesn't imply that to me at all.  I mean you cannot roll an auto engine out of the shed and drive it down the road.  You put into a car and connect things up ... and eventually you can take the car for a drive.

Answer (score 1):

Lucene is a search engine. You would use lucene in a project if you wanted a fast indexed search. More details can be found on http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html